# How to modify specific lines in text file using C#?

Tags: c#, text-files

I have srt file with movie subtitles like this:

1
00:00:00,082 --> 00:00:04,352
bbb bbb bb
bbb bb

2
00:00:08,486 --> 00:00:12,662
bbb bbb bbb

3
00:00:12,824 --> 00:00:14,963
bbb
bbbb bb

I want to add constant value to minutes (so subtitles will be displayed later). How can i do this?

I already have this code:

```cs
class MainClass
{

    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"sb.srt",FileMode.Open,FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
            {
                while( sr.Read()!=-1 )
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(sr.ReadLine());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You do know that there is millions of programs that does this already? Most players does this as well

Comment: Question's title is misleading.

Comment: @jv42 then change the title, don't vote to close

Comment: I would avoid `while( sr.Read()!=-1 )` to test end of file in .NET, as there are better ways to detect it. And maybe in your case, you only want to read the whole file, and then there are also special methods for that, including some that don't require Streams and StreamReaders, like `File.ReadAllText(string path)` for instance.

Comment: @Oskar: the vote to close is because the question is too generic, like "please code this for me".

Comment: @Oskar: but it's democratic hey, it requires more votes than just mine.

Comment: @jv42 Yeah I know, just wanted to point out that a misleading title is no reason to vote to close. But if that's not the reason, go ahead. But there's a reason for us being able to edit peoples post

Comment: Sorry if question is too generic.

Comment: @Arvangen: IMHO it's not really too 'generic', rather it doesn't show whether you have researched the question and tried things yourself before asking for help. That's usually not welcome here. I'm not saying you didn't try, just that your question doesn't show this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a complete program to do it. Just change the timespan to be how much you want to add

```
const string format = @"hh\:mm\:ss\,fff";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = File.ReadAllText("sb.srt");
            Regex r = new Regex(@"(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d),(\d\d\d)");
            input = r.Replace(input, m=> AddTime(m));
            File.WriteAllText("sb.srt", input);
        }

        private static string AddTime(Match m)
        {
            TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.ParseExact(m.Value, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            t += new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
            return t.ToString(format);
        }
```

Comment: In first line of AddTime method I replace TimeSpan to DateTime and it work almost good. For TimeSpan(0,0,1) input: 00:00:00,082 --> 00:00:04,352 and output: 12:00:01,082 --> 12:00:05,352 . 12 hours? wtf? But 1 second is added correctly.

Comment: Why are you using DateTime? This `is` a timespan

Comment: Error CS0117: `System.TimeSpan' does not contain a definition for `ParseExact' (CS0117) (sub)  I have this error, but DateTime class have ParseExact method. For now I am using MonoDevelop (I don't know if it make a difference)

Comment: Ok, now I see on MSDN page that TimeSpan have this method. I think this can be Mono fault

Answer (score 2):

I would use a regular expression matching the lines

```
00:00:08,486 --> 00:00:12,662
```

and then use `Regex.Replace` with a custom `MatchEvaluator`, which parses the time code, adds the time difference and returns the new time code as string.

A simple Regex for the time code would be

```
"^\s*(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d),(\d\d\d)\s*-->\s*(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d),(\d\d\d)\s*$"
```

For the evaluator, you could construct two `TimeSpan` values from the respective fields of the match, add the time difference and construct the result string using `String.Format`.

This way, you can load the entire text file into a string using `File.ReadAllText`, process it and  write it back using `File.WriteAllText`, which makes the core routine a three-liner :)

PS: Don't forget to use the `RegexOptions.Multiline` option in order to get `"^"` and `"$"` to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
    private static string ProcessLine(string line, int seconds)
    {
        var regex = new Regex(@"^(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d\d\d) --> (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d\d\d)");

        var match = regex.Match(line);

        if (match.Success)
        {
            var from = AddSeconds(match.Groups[1].ToString(), seconds);
            var to = AddSeconds(match.Groups[2].ToString(), seconds);
            return string.Format("{0} --> {1}", from, to);
        }
        else
        {
            return line;
        }
    }

    private static string AddSeconds(string timestamp, int seconds)
    {
        var datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(timestamp, "HH:mm:ss,fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        return datetime.AddSeconds(seconds).ToString("HH:mm:ss,fff"); 
    }
```

Replace `sb.AppendLine(sr.ReadLine());` with `sb.AppendLine(ProcessLine(sr.ReadLine(), 60));` in your original code.